# Reordering a list in a given order

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

I want to reorder my list in a given order,
For example I have a list of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
this has an index of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] and lets say the new ordered list would have an order of [3,5,6,1,2,4,0] which would result in ['d','f','g', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'a'].

How would you result in such code?

I thought of using for loop by doing the

```
 for i in range(Len(list))
```

and after that I thought go using append or creating a new list? maybe but I'm not sure if I'm approaching this right.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is iterate the list of indexes, and use it to access the list of elements, like this:

```py
elems =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
idx =  [3,5,6,1,2,4,0]

result = [elems[i] for i in idx]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['d', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'a']
```

Comment: I hope the list comprehension syntax is clear, you can of course do it with a regular for-loop

Comment: Thank you so much for the instructions! I get how it works now. Just another question that continues from this. How would you reorder this list back to [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]? I tired reordering the mutated list using the index list that is provided but it doesn't rlly work that way. Would there be any way I could still use the given index list to reorder the list back?

Comment: ^ @user14004788 You could post another follow-up question. But make it clear what's your "reorder the list back".

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

my_list =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

def my_function(my_list, index):
    return np.take(my_list, index)

print(my_function(my_list, [3,5,6,1,2,4,0]))
```

```
Output: ['d' 'f' 'g' 'b' 'c' 'e' 'a']
```